# Mouse hover not working on entire website after wordpress update

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm new in stackoverflow, and the problem is strange. I'm not a code savvy guy so I really need you guys to help me out on this.

After the latest wordpress updates to 3.9.1, the theme hover function is not working anymore. Not on the thumbnail on homepage nor the menu bar.

http://nd-channel.com/

Is there any JavaScript error occur or something?

Appreciate your kind reply on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi AstroCB, It says $ is not a function and this is the only error msg shown on the console. Anyway to resolve it ?

Comment: use jQuery in place of $

Comment: @mrpotocnik i got it sorted out. It is plugin conflict. Many thanks for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got some console errors. I took [a screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/3Z1e2N3R0O3w) so you can see it. And it links to [this file](http://cl.ly/image/2N2X2N3X2O0X). This javascript looks like it is associated with a slider plugin. I would check your plugins to make sure they are all up to date and are compatible with the newest version of Wordpress.

Comment: Many Thanks for the solution, I've done check through my plugin and found a JQuery plugin which is causing this issues and it has been fixed after deactivated. Appreciate much for your fast respond.